# How to connect orientdb database using java?

Tags: java, database, orientdb

I tried to connect using orientdb database with java. like this
    `OrientGraph odb = new OrientGraph("plocal:C:/Users/USER/Desktop/orientdb/databases/testJ", "admin", "admin");`

Its showing an error

> HTTP Status 500 - Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/orientechnologies/orient/core/db/record/ODatabaseRecord

My dependencies..

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
        <artifactId>orientdb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
      <artifactId>orientdb-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.tinkerpop</groupId>
      <artifactId>pipes</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.tinkerpop.blueprints</groupId>
       <artifactId>blueprints-core</artifactId>
       <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tinkerpop.blueprints</groupId>
        <artifactId>blueprints-orient-graph</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

help me to resolve the error..
thank you in advance

Comment: Try `"file:///Users/...."`

Comment: this answer might help if you have created the database in correct way:http://stackoverflow.com/a/22893008/2841481 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/26846163/2841481

Comment: `"file:///Users/...."` not working. it showing.

HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Cannot create database

Comment: @RiyasPK Why did you unaccepted the answer? Anything wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ODatabaseRecord seems to be deprecated from new version. I made following changes to your code and it worked (remove all other dependencies).

**pom**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
  <artifactId>orientdb-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
  <artifactId>orientdb-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.8</version>
</dependency>
```

**Java Code**

```
OrientGraphFactory ogf = new OrientGraphFactory(
            "plocal:C:/Users/USER/Desktop/orientdb/databases/testJ", "admin", "admin");
    OrientGraph og = ogf.getTx();

    try {
        System.out.println("Features = " + og.getFeatures());
    } finally {
        og.shutdown();
    }
```

Note: I found clue [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.orientdb.user/20226).

Comment: I got problems using your code. It is just not working. I am using "root" "root" as login data. Why do you use admin ?

Comment: @FlorianNeiss I used `admin` because thats the default user for orientdb. Check details [here](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/Security.html).

Comment: @FlorianNeiss Actually the `admin` is used for the `plocal` connections, while `root` for `remote` connections.